# How to fix FileNotFoundException after deleting hudi dataset partition on s3?

Tags: apache-hudi

Have mistakenly deleted Hudi partition 'pt=2024-01' on s3 and getting FileNotFound Exception when I try to update the Hudi table with the same partition name .
I used spark to remove the footprints of that partition but it didnt work.
Have also tried multiple things like removing commit files from .hoodie folder for this partition

```
val basePath = <<TablePath>>

val df  = spark.read.format("org.apache.hudi").
    option("hoodie.datasource.read.extract.partition.values.from.path", true).
    load(basePath)

val delDf = df.filter(<<Filter Condition>>)



delDf.
    write.
    format("org.apache.hudi").
    option(OPERATION_OPT_KEY,"delete").
    option(PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY, <<Precombine Key>>).
    option(RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY, <<Record Key>>). // Add partition key if required
    option("hoodie.metrics.on", "false").
    option("hoodie.write.tagged.record.storage.level", "DISK_ONLY").
    option("hoodie.write.status.storage.level", "DISK_ONLY").    
    mode(Append).
    save(basePath)
```

The Error logs can be found here -:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieUpsertException: Failed to upsert for commit time 20240112113537886
at org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.BaseWriteHelper.write(BaseWriteHelper.java:64)
at org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.execute(SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.java:45)
at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:113)
at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:97)
at org.apache.hudi.client.SparkRDDWriteClient.upsert(SparkRDDWriteClient.java:157)
at org.apache.hudi.DataSourceUtils.doWriteOperation(DataSourceUtils.java:213)
at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:304)
at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:519)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:519)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:495)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
at com.licious.dataplatform.datalake.pipelines.gold.MonthABTest$.execute(MonthABTest.scala:95)
at com.licious.dataplatform.datalake.pipelines.gold.MonthABTest$.main(MonthABTest.scala:104)
at com.licious.dataplatform.datalake.pipelines.gold.MonthABTest.main(MonthABTest.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:740)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 42.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 42.0 (TID 1214) (ip-10-1-5-17.ap-south-1.compute.internal executor 8): org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieIOException: Failed to read from Parquet file s3://ls-dp/prod/datalake/data/test/customer/monthly_user_properties/pt=2024-01/8df75d2d-023f-48a0-b372-af726deb6c41-0_0-62-2170_20240102172043917.parquet
at org.apache.hudi.common.util.ParquetUtils.getHoodieKeyIterator(ParquetUtils.java:181)
at org.apache.hudi.common.util.ParquetUtils.fetchHoodieKeys(ParquetUtils.java:196)
at org.apache.hudi.common.util.ParquetUtils.fetchHoodieKeys(ParquetUtils.java:147)
at org.apache.hudi.io.HoodieKeyLocationFetchHandle.locations(HoodieKeyLocationFetchHandle.java:62)
at org.apache.hudi.index.simple.HoodieSimpleIndex.lambda$fetchRecordLocations$33972fb4$1(HoodieSimpleIndex.java:155)
at org.apache.hudi.data.HoodieJavaRDD.lambda$flatMap$a6598fcb$1(HoodieJavaRDD.java:117)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(JavaRDDLike.scala:125)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:183)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1474)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://ls-dp/prod/datalake/data/test/customer/monthly_user_properties/pt=2024-01/8df75d2d-023f-48a0-b372-af726deb6c41-0_0-62-2170_20240102172043917.parquet'
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:521)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.getFileStatus(EmrFileSystem.java:613)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.build(ParquetReader.java:337)
at org.apache.hudi.common.util.ParquetUtils.getHoodieKeyIterator(ParquetUtils.java:178)
... 20 more
```

Comment: Have also tried multiple things like deleting files from .hoodie folder etc

Comment: Plz share the exception msg

Comment: @parisni Please check the post now !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have metatata table enabled (default) ? If so delete the `.hoodie/metadata` folder as it still references the deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly load the location as a parquet format.

Pyspark approach

1. Delete the **`.hoodie`** folder
2. Load the file in df `spark.read.parquet(path)`
3. Drop the `_hoodie*` columns.
4. Rewrite the data in required location.